how to use link in new next.js in my project
If someone doesn't mind, will you please take a look at my folders/files, which I've shown in a screenshot and then look at the code in the page.tsx file for the homepage of my website. The link isn't working correctly when I go from my home page to any other page, and I keep getting a 404 error. code folders/files
i've kept trying to change the link by looking at the online documentation but I can't figure it out.

The project.tsx, writing.tsx needs to be renamed page.tsx. In the App Router, the folder s in the app is the route but each folder must have a page.tsx for the route to be properly recognised.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing
